# How to reproduce tabbed effect for stacking images?

Tags: css-float

I would like to reproduce this effect on a web page:

http://www.ronnysinc.com/gallery.html

On the example page whenever you click a different tab you get a different set of images to load in the same window. I figure this is achieved using CSS and floating layers on top of each other. I don't have a clue how to code a project like this but the effect is kick azz.

So CSS geru's, can any of you show example code to achieve this effect?

Comment: Your question isn't about images, but about tabbed HTML content in general. Google 'css tabs' and 'jQuery tabs', then come back when you have some code to show us. SO requires that you have started work before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you just need tabbed layout provided, for example, by popular and well known [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

**Quickstart**

You will need to add links in your HTML document for `jQuery` itself, `jQuery UI` library and `CSS` theme for `jQuery UI` (all come with the initial zip package):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
```

then you should activate your tabs:

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#animals").tabs();
  })
</script>
```

and finally, you could enjoy your tabs in the site, here is the pattern for 3 tabs:

```html
<div id="animals">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fish">Fish</a></li>
    <li><a href="#birds">Birds</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lizards">Lizards</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fish">
    . . .
    fish content
    . . .
  </div>
  <div id="birds">
    . . .
    bird content
    . . .
  </div>
  <div id="lizards">
    . . .
    lizard content
    . . .
  </div>
</div>
```

All inside div's are welcome for your ccs-floats, images and whatever.

Also, you can explore the source code of the site to see the techniques and tricks (btw, I did find `jQuery` embedded there).